# Pretty print the JSON returned by express in Node.JS

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm trying to follow this great [design recommendation documentation](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#pretty-print-gzip) for my server development in Node.JS regarding the JSON pretty formatting when returning it to the caller.

I can't figure out to do so when returning a file though:

```
app.get('/data.txt', function(req, res){
    return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/views/myData.json'));
});
```

Would you have any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `res.sendFile` is going to simply send the contents of your file, which in this case is a text file and since the extension is `txt` you're going to get a returned content-type of text/plain, no? What are you hoping to pretty-print?

Comment: sorry, extension was wrong. the file contains some json

Comment: @goul Did you consider using a browser extension to convert and see the raw JSON into a pretty JSON ? or try POSTMAN app on chrome ?

Comment: From the link I copied in my post, I would want the use not having to handle this

Answer (score 0):

You can simply require the JSON file using :

```
let fileContents = require(path.resolve(__dirname + '/views/myData.json'));
```

And then

```
app.get('/data.txt', function(req, res){
    return res.send(fileContents);
});
```

*Note: This approach doesn't send the file.It sends the contents of the JSON file in response.*